# Injection of IUrlHelper in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-1.0

In **RC1**, `IUrlHelper` could be injected in services (with `services.AddMvc()` in startup class)

This doesn't work anymore in **RC2**. Does anybody know how to do it in **RC2** as just newing up a `UrlHelper` requires an `ActionContext` object. Don't know how to get that outside a controller.

Answer (score 86, accepted):

**.NET Core 3+ and .NET 5 Update (2020 and later)**

Use `LinkGenerator` as detailed in @Dmitry Pavlov's [answer on this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59791439/5101). It's injectable as part of the web framework, and works with the `HttpContext` already available in controllers, or accessible in other services by injecting the `IHttpContextAccessor`.

For **ASP.NET Core RC2** there is an [issue for this on the github repo](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/3936). Instead of injecting the `IUrlHelper`, take an `IUrlHelperFactory`. It also sounds like you'd need the `IActionContextAccessor` injected as a `Controller` no longer has a public property `ActionContext`.

Register the dependency:

```
services.AddSingleton<IActionContextAccessor, ActionContextAccessor>();
```

Then depend on it:

```
public SomeService(IUrlHelperFactory urlHelperFactory,
                   IActionContextAccessor actionContextAccessor)
{
 
    var urlHelper =
        urlHelperFactory.GetUrlHelper(actionContextAccessor.ActionContext);
}
```

Then use it as you see fit.

Comment: I'm not sure what to say, perhaps there is a bug - otherwise there might be something in the https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements repo?

Comment: though this is the accepted answer from 2016, as with most things in tech, things change with time. As of 2021, the better answer for ASP.NET Core 3+ and ASP.NET 5 is to use the `LinkGenerator` type as detailed in @Dmitry Pavlov's answer below.

Answer (score 75):

For **ASP.NET Core 3.x** app just inject `IHttpContextAccessor` and [`LinkGenerator`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing?#url-generation-with-linkgenerator) to your controller or service. They should be already available in `DI`.

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing;

namespace Coding-Machine.NET
{
    public class MyService
    {
        private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _accessor;
        private readonly LinkGenerator _generator;

        public MyService(IHttpContextAccessor accessor, LinkGenerator generator)
        {
            _accessor = accessor;
            _generator = generator;
        }

        private string GenerateConfirmEmailLink()
        {
            var callbackLink = _generator.GetUriByPage(_accessor.HttpContext,
                page: "/Account/ConfirmEmail",
                handler: null, 
                values: new {area = "Identity", userId = 123, code = "ASDF1234"});

            return callbackLink;
        }
    }
}
```

If your app can't resolve `IHttpContextAccessor` just add this to `DI`:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
     services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
}
```

Comment: The only downside of this approach is that you lose every custom-made extension method on IUrlHelper.
Sadly in that case you have to rely on `IUrlHelperFactory`

Comment: If we have controller level route value, this method expects to add them instead prefill. Do you know anyway to prefill it.

Answer (score 26):

For **Net Core 2.0**

Add this after `service.AddMvc()`

```
services.AddSingleton<IActionContextAccessor, ActionContextAccessor>();
services.AddScoped<IUrlHelper>(factory =>
{
    var actionContext = factory.GetService<IActionContextAccessor>()
                                   .ActionContext;
    return new UrlHelper(actionContext);
});
```

Comment: Added this code to my `Startup.cs`, injected IUrlHelper into my tag helper class as `urlHelper`. When I call `urlHelper.Action()` it throws `IndexOutOfRangeException`.

Answer (score 5):

For .Net Core 2.0

```
services.AddMvc();

services.AddScoped<IUrlHelper>(x =>
{
   var actionContext = x.GetRequiredService<IActionContextAccessor>().ActionContext;
   var factory = x.GetRequiredService<IUrlHelperFactory>();
   return factory.GetUrlHelper(actionContext);
});
```

Comment: This works for .Net Core 6.0 as well.

Answer (score 3):

**ASP.NET Core 2.0**

*Install*

```
PM> Install-Package AspNetCore.IServiceCollection.AddIUrlHelper
```

*Use*

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
   ... 
   services.AddUrlHelper();
   ... 
}
```

*Disclaimer: author of this package*

Comment: Disclaimer: You are the author of this package

Comment: I am trying to access IUrlHelper on a Hub in aspnet signalr core 2.1 will your package work?

Comment: @PhathutshedzoKhabubu package just registers `IUrlHelper` in `ServiceCollection` with necessary dependencies. As far as `DI` is available, `IUrlHelper` will also be available.

Comment: I installed this package in an asp,net core 2.0.6 application and tried injecting the IUrlHelper in a singnalR Core Hub but it was not injected and got back null so thats way I raised that and note I added `services.AddUrlHelper();` after `services.AddMvc()`

Comment: @PhathutshedzoKhabubu How are you accessing `IUrlHelper` ? if you're injecting it into constructor and it's not available, then you'll get exception instead of `null`

Comment: I tried via constructor injection than I got an exception but Via IUrlHelperFactory the action context is null therefore it throws an exception that the argument can not be null

Comment: @PhathutshedzoKhabubu, have you solved the issue? I have the same problem

Comment: @MohammedNoureldin @PhathutshedzoKhabubu `IUrlHepler` is only available inside HttpContext. You can't access it outside, let's say in a background job, etc.

Answer (score 0):

**For ASP.Net Core 2.0** you must not inject an IUrlHelper. It’s available as a property of the controller. ControllerBase.Url is an IUrlHelper instance.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.  Often you don't want to take a dependency on a concrete controller in a class.

Comment: Agree with @Stephen . I want to inject the `IUrlHelper` into a Ui Service which has no dependency on a controller. I mean, why would it?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken the behavior of IUrlHelper depends on current Route and RouteData. In the case of direct injecting into Ui Service you may end up with surprising results.

Comment: @OleksandrDudnyk you're absolutely right. I've faced this "surprising" result. Is there any alternative for IUrlHelper to use correctly in a class?

Comment: What's your source on "you must not inject and IUrlHelper"?