# how to get IUrlHelper from inside Html helper

Tags: asp.net-core

I need the url helper inside an html Helper so I have

`IHtmlHelper<T> html`
and need to get `IUrlHelper`

I tried this:

```
html.ViewContext.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService(typeof(IUrlHelper));
```

but it returns null

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37322339/2410379

Answer (score 9, accepted):

got the answer here: https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/5051
so it looks like this:

```
public static IHtmlContent MyHelper(this IHtmlHelper<T> html){
    var urlHelperFactory = (IUrlHelperFactory)html.ViewContext.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService(typeof(IUrlHelperFactory));            
    var urlHelper = urlHelperFactory.GetUrlHelper(aweInfo.Html.ViewContext);
```