# ASP net Core How to generate route url inside a IHostedService?

Tags: asp.net-core-2.0

In an ASP.net 2 MVC app, I've implemented some background tasks via the IHostedServices interface, similar to the idea exposed [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/cesardelatorre/2017/11/18/implementing-background-tasks-in-microservices-with-ihostedservice-and-the-backgroundservice-class-net-core-2-x/).

Now I need to generate Urls targeting internal routes and I'm struggling to access something like an ActionContext object or routing object having methods to do that.

Any idea?

Comment: This code in [ASP.Net Core 2.0: Creating UrlHelper without request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46096068/asp-net-core-2-0-creating-urlhelper-without-request) may allow you do do what you need to, but it is not ideal.

Comment: Indeed... Way too complex. I think I'm heading towards generating those urls at a later point in the code flow. Thanks